# Cannot run WiFi sketch on ESP-01

Tags: esp8266

I can upload simple sketch on my ESP-01 like:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello there"); 
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println("Hello from loop");
  delay(1000);
}
```

I also ran successfully the sample ESPWebServer -> HelloServer

But if just modify my sketch to include `#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>`

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Hello there"); 
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println("Hello from loop");
  delay(1000);
}
```

I got this result in the serial monitor:

```
  ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:4, boot mode:(3,7)

wdt reset
load 0x4010f000, len 1384, room 16 
tail 8
chksum 0x2d
csum 0x2d
vbb28d4a3
~ld
```

My ESP-01 is connected to my computer through FT232RL FTDI with the following cabling:

- FTDI GND - GND
- ESP TX - FTDI RX
- ESP RX - FTDI TX
- ESP VCC - VCC 3.3V
- ESP GND - GND
- ESP CH_PD - VCC
- ESP GPIO2 - VCC
- ESP GPI00 - GND to upload sketch, VCC to run sketch

Here is a picture of my cabling (the USB of both the TTL and power supply MB102 are connected to my laptop):

[image: Cabling ESP-01 to TTL]

Also, regularly my sketch fails to load correctly:

-Sometimes it does not load at all and I get this after compilation before uploading starts:

```
warning: espcomm_sync failed
error: espcomm_open failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

- Sometimes it fails at the end of the upload:

```
Uploading 256064 bytes from C:\Users\20000263\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_32221/ESP01-Basic.ino.bin to flash at 0x00000000
................................................................................ [ 31% ]
................................................................................ [ 63% ]
................................................................................ [ 95% ]
..........warning: espcomm_send_command: didn't receive command response
warning: espcomm_send_command(FLASH_DOWNLOAD_DATA) failed
warning: espcomm_send_command: wrong direction/command: 0x01 0x03, expected 0x01 0x04
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
error: espcomm_upload_mem failed
```

Any idea about what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

FTDI adapters often don't provide enough current to run the power-hungry wifi features of the ESP8266. So as soon as you fire up wifi, you brownout the chip and cause it to reset.

Use a battery, a dedicated ESP8266 flasher, a 3.3v LDO, or something besides the on-board 3.3v connection the USB-Serial adapter provides.

Comment: I already have a separated power supply for the ESP8266 of this type: [MB102 breadboard power supply module](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51MVjxjX14L.jpg)